# Timescaledb JPA time_bucket function

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, timescaledb

I want to use timescaledb in my spring boot application like:

```
@Query("""select time_bucket(':bucket' minutes) as bucket, avg(data) as value
from h_table ht
where
   ...
group by bucket""", nativeQuery=true)
fun getByDeviceAndCode(@Param("bucket") bucket:Int,
                       ...) : List<ResultData>
```

but I've got an error:

```
 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type interval: ":bucket minutes"
```

how can I pass :bucket parameter to sql?

thx,
Zamek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a mistake in the ending quote, and the time column seems missing. It has to be as follows (where `time_col` should be replaced with the name of your time column):

```
select time_bucket(':bucket minutes', time_col) as bucket, avg(data) as value ...
```

https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/time_bucket/#sample-usage

If you still get the error, try to cast it explicitly to a postgres interval with something like this:

```
select time_bucket(cast(':bucket minutes' as interval), time_col) as bucket, avg(data) as value ...
```

To avoid problems, I would also change the type of `bucket` to a String and include the time unit (`minutes`) inside it. This way it will be treated as a whole string and avoid issues with single quotes:

```
select time_bucket(cast(:bucket as interval), time_col) as bucket, avg(data) as value ...
```

Comment: yes, you are right, the last is the solution, it works for me
thx a lot